# How to specify a collection name in $http call?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mongodb-rest

I have multiple collections in my MongoDB db. I have an angularJS application which has to post to different collections depending on the context.

How do I specify the name of the collection in the $http call and have a common REST API ?

$http function:

```
$http({
    method:"post",
    url:"http://localhost:8080/insertIntoTable",
    headers:"",
    data:"data"
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $window.alert('Rest API successful');
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $window.alert('Unsuccessful');
});
```

Post method in the back-end:

```
app.post('/insertIntoTable',function(req,res){
    //Establish Connection between client and server
    MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
       //Connection Status Display
       if(err)
           console.log('Error while establishing connection with MongoDB',err);
       else
           console.log('Successfully established connection with MongoDB');
       var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
       collection.insert({ "name": "abc", "email": "xyz" });
       db.close();
       console.log('Connection with MongoDB is terminated');
   })
});
```

In the above code, I want to pass the value of the variable: collectionName in the $http call. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Node.js

This approach reads a property from the [request](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) query string and uses it as table name. To prevent security issues, a validation on tableName is also required.

```
// list of valid table names to avoid security issues.
var validTables = ['users', 'customers', 'orders'];
app.post('/insertIntoTable/:tableName', function(req, res) {
   var tableName= req.params.tableName;
   // verify if the table name is a valid table name.
   if (validTables.indexOf(tableName) === -1) {
        res.status(404).send('Not found');       // HTTP status 404: NotFound
        return;               
   }
   // use tableName as collection name. 
}
```

#### In AngularJs

In the client side, send the table name as a regular path, i.e. make the request as in the example below:

```
$http({
    method:"post",
    url:"http://localhost:8080/insertIntoTable/users", // note "users"
    data:"data"
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // process success
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // process error
});
```

Comment: While this is a valid and correct answer to the question asked by the poster, it should be noted that hardcoding and passing key database identifiers like collection names, table names, database names etc from client side is not good programming practice from security standpoint. instead cross-ref on server side.

Comment: @user3658423 : I am new to this and did not realize about the security issue. Could you please direct me towards useful resources on cross referencing on the server side ? Thanks

Comment: @DishaMathad I edited the answer to include a validation on the table name.

Comment: also you could read this useful article http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before